Configuring datachart bar color in ApexCharts based on bar value %
I'm new to HA and struggling to get my head around everything. How to make the bar colors change based on the values? I want the NordPool electricity price data chart to show the high price bars red, middle orange, low green etc, but I want them to be set depending on the max price of the particular day, lets say, the max shown price of the cart today is 50 EUR, so the 80%-100% of the max price will show up red, 60%-80% orange etc. Currently I have them set as 0-10 EUR = blue 10-20 green etc. But that's not convenient if all the hourly prices of the day are, lets say in a range of 0-10 - then all the bars are shown in blue.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.
This is the code for the chart right now:
type: custom:apexcharts-card
graph_span: 36h
experimental:
  color_threshold: true
header:
  title: Energy price today (€/kWh)
  show: true
span:
  start: day
now:
  show: true
  label: Now
series:
  - entity: sensor.nordpool_energyprices
    color: green
    type: column
    show:
      extremas: true
    color_threshold:
      - value: 0
        color: blue
      - value: 5
        color: lightgreen
      - value: 10
        color: green
      - value: 15
        color: yellow
      - value: 20
        color: gold
      - value: 25
        color: orange
      - value: 30
        color: red
    float_precision: 2
    data_generator: |
      return entity.attributes.times.map((time, index) => {
        return [new Date(time).getTime(), entity.attributes.prices[index]];
      });
yaxis:
  - decimals: 2
    apex_config:
      tickAmount: 10


